# How does non-ideal charging affect the life of a Li-Ion/Li-Po battery?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

For lithium ion batteries, the standard way of charging them is CC - CV - cutoff. My question is, what are the effects of not following this pattern?

For example, what if you charge with just a constant voltage source and a resistor (assuming the max current is below the max charging current of the batter)? Or what happens if you charge in bursts (again, keeping the current below the max)?

How much do these affect the energy stored in the battery, and how do they affect its overall internal resistance and life? Does it have any effect, or is it just that its slower than CC/CV?

Comment: What do you mean with "just a power source and a resistor"? I've seen people charge their batteries with a lab power supply and that's just a source of power and a current limitation. And I think charging in burst just slows down the charging process nothing more. Why do you ask?

Comment: @Petar i mean a constant voltage source with a fixed resistor, as opposed to a constant current source like a lab psu in current limiting mode